# How to suppress a lint warning in some code but not everywhere?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, static-analysis, lint

I'm trying to suppress `HardcodedStringLiteral` in places that the string is a named code reference, not customer facing.  Specifically, this is an issue with named Dagger injection.

If I have, for example,

```kotlin
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val resourceRetriever: ResourceRetriever,
    @Named("thing_one") private val thingOne: BehaviorRelay<String>,
    @Named("thing_two") private val thingTwo: BehaviorRelay<String>,
    ...
)
```

I get `HardcodedStringLiteral` warnings on `thing_one` and `thing_two`.  I could add `@Suppress("HardCodedStringLiteral")` to every `@Named` but there are hundreds of them through the project.  I don't want to just suppress it at the file, class, or project level because I *do* care about other hardcoded string literals.

I was hoping to configure something (lint.xml, lint options in build.gradle, etc.) that basically says

```xml
<issue id="HardCodedStringLiteral">
    <ignore anything="@Named" />
</issue>
```

but can't figure out how to define `anything="@Named"`.

Comment: Does not answer your question, but why don't you make those literals constants?

Comment: I thought about that.  I'd rather just define a rule in one place instead of changing this everywhere.  Using constants though would be beneficial, but would be a bigger change than I'm hoping for.